# what information can be gleaned from Model.Exception in .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I'm currently using

```
Model.Exception.Message
```

but wondering if there are other properties that will provide other information.  What I'd like to know is the page on which the exception was thrown if that's at all possible to determine what function was happening when the exception occurred.

Edit (adding more information):

I'm using this on a cshtml page in .net mvc. I know there are exception handler libraries that will do everything for me, but I'd like to know what I can leverage out of this dynamic expression.

Comment: This question is incredibly vague. It looks like C#, but not tagged as such, nor is it tagged with ASP.NET MVC so you could be using some other kind of framework. The question also doesnt give enough code sample to be able to appropriately answer your question.

Comment: updated my OP to provide more info.

Comment: Try `Model.Exception.ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't provide enough details only a general pointer that the `Exception` class in .NET provides several properties including a `Stacktrace` - so: yes, you can get more information than just the `Message`... for the MSDN reference see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx